# Have Python Discord bot read different reactions

Tags: python, discord.py

I was trying to make a simple Rock Paper Scissors python discord bot, using reactions to a message. I researched and adapted some of the following code and tried to use it, but I realized that it would only work if you reacted to the message with the paper first, and then the rock (btw there is no scissors because I realized this was a problem).

```
import discord
import random
import asyncio

TOKEN = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    username = str(message.author).split('#')[0]
    user_message = str(message.content)
    channel = str(message.channel.name)
    print(f'{username}: {user_message} ({channel})')
    random_choice = 0

    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if user_message.lower() == 'p!rps':
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors. Please react to this message with a rock, paper (), or scissors emoji to play the game!')

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send('Timed out. Pleas re-enter command to play again.')
        else:
            random_choice = random.randint(1, 3)
            if random_choice == 1:
                await channel.send('You choose paper. I choose rock.')
                await channel.send('You win!')
            if random_choice == 2:
                await channel.send('You choose paper. I choose paper.')
                await channel.send('We tied!')
            if random_choice == 3:
                await channel.send('You choose paper. I choose scissors.')
                await channel.send('I win!')
            
        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) == ''

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send('Timed out. Pleas re-enter command to play again.')
        else:
            random_choice = random.randint(1, 3)
            if random_choice == 1:
                await channel.send('You choose rock. I choose rock.')
                await channel.send('We tied!')
            if random_choice == 2:
                await channel.send('You choose rock. I choose paper.')
                await channel.send('I win!')
            if random_choice == 3:
                await channel.send('You choose rock. I choose scissors.')
                await channel.send('You win!')
            

                return



client.run(TOKEN)
```

Could someone fix the code for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ('', '', '✂️')` in your check.

Edit: Using your code, this should look something like this:

```py
    if user_message.lower() == 'p!rps':
        channel = message.channel
        await channel.send('Welcome to Rock Paper Scissors. Please react to this message with a rock, paper (), or scissors emoji to play the game!')

        def check(reaction, user):
            return user == message.author and str(reaction.emoji) in ('', '', '✂️')

        try:
            reaction, user = await client.wait_for('reaction_add', timeout=60.0, check=check)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            await channel.send('Timed out. Pleas re-enter command to play again.')

        if str(reaction.emoji) == '':
            random_choice = random.randint(1, 3)
            if random_choice == 1:
                await channel.send('You choose paper. I choose rock.')
                await channel.send('You win!')
            if random_choice == 2:
                await channel.send('You choose paper. I choose paper.')
                await channel.send('We tied!')
            if random_choice == 3:
                await channel.send('You choose paper. I choose scissors.')
                await channel.send('I win!')
        elif str(reaction.emoji) == '':
            random_choice = random.randint(1, 3)
            if random_choice == 1:
                await channel.send('You choose rock. I choose rock.')
                await channel.send('We tied!')
            if random_choice == 2:
                await channel.send('You choose rock. I choose paper.')
                await channel.send('I win!')
            if random_choice == 3:
                await channel.send('You choose rock. I choose scissors.')
                await channel.send('You win!')
        elif str(reaction.emoji) == '✂️':
            #do the logic for choosing scissors here
```

Comment: Sorry, I am kinda new to Python, could you please implement that into the code?

Comment: I edited my comment, I hope this is more clear